# combine or cumulate many comments into one comment if posted within similar time or same user

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, database-design

**Question:**  I want cumulate or combine many comments  into one if they are posted in similar time by the same user. What is the best way of approaching this?

**Currently:** I have DB table that has comments written by each user, structure as follow:
`ID, comment, timestamp, userid`

**Example:**  All users have a current status page, here you can view  what they  have been upto. For a example if the user uploads a new photo, comment will appear to show they have uploaded a photo. But if the user uploads many photos at once, let say 10 in the last 30mins, then there will be 10 different comments, but i want to combine or cumulate this into one comment instead of spamming the status page.

**Technology used:**  MYSQL, PHP

thanks, if more info needed please ask.

Comment: Why don't you check the last comment the user did and see if it was not more than 30 minutes ago. If that evaluates to true just append the comment to the old comment, otherwise create a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

you should not create multiple comments if it is all the same

make 3 tables:

**photos** [id, src,  title, date, etc...]
**comments** [id, comment, timestamp, userid, etc...]
**photos_comments** [id, photo_id, comment_id]

when you upload multiple comments at once you will create only 1 new record in the **comments** table, but connect it to multiple photos in the **photos_comments** table (this is called many to many relationship)

when you want to get all the comments that related to a photo (lets say photo with id=10), you can pull it from the DB with this query:

`SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id IN (SELECT comment_id FROM comments_photos WHERE photo_id=10)`

or even better, with joins:

`SELECT comments.* FROM comments INNER JOIN photos_comments ON photos_comments.comment_id=comments.id WHERE photos_comments.photo_id=10`